# Elastic Search - Query only searches 5 characters

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-query

I have this issue where regardless of what value I send in a query, I don't get any results past the fifth character searched.

Example:

- {"match": {"name": "benjami"}} - Will return no results
- {"match": {"name": "benja"}} - Return results with name Benja...
- {"match": {"name": "benjamin"}} - Return results with name Benjamin

Index:

"name" : {
"type": "string",
"analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
}

settings:

```
"analyzer": {
    "edge_ngram_analyzer":{
        "type": "custom", "tokenizer": "standard", "filter": ["lowercase","edge_ngram_filter"]}},
"filter": {
    "edge_ngram_filter":{
        "type": "edge_ngram", "min_gram": 1, "max_gram": 40}}
```

Using term vectors I have found that the field is indexed correctly. The issue lies somewhere with elastic search not searching my full query value. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Thank you so much for helping out, I'm using elastic search version 5.6!

Index

```
"properties" : { "searchid": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
        "otherId": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"},
        "name": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"},
}
```

Settings

```
"settings": {
        "number_of_replicas": 0,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {"edge_ngram_filter": {"type": "edge_ngram", "min_gram": 2, "max_gram": 80}},
            "analyzer": {
                "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "edge_ngram_filter"],
                },
                "short_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "edge_ngram_filter"],
                },
                "case_sensitive": {"type": "custom", "tokenizer": "whitespace", "filter": []}
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                  "type": "edge_ngram",
                  "min_gram": 2,
                  "max_gram": 40,
                  "token_chars": [
                    "letter","digit"
                  ]
                }
        },
        },
    },
```

Query

```
{'query': 
{'function_score': 
{'query': 
{'bool': {'should': [{'multi_match': {'query': 'A162412350', 'fields': ['otherId']}}}]}}, 
'functions': [{'field_value_factor': {'field': 'positionOrActive', 'modifier': 'none', 'missing': '0', 'factor': '1.1'}}], 'score_mode': 'sum', 'boost_mode': 'sum'}}, 'size': 25}
```

Doc Results

```
[{u'otherId': u'A1624903499',
  u'positionOrActive': 0,
  'searchScore': 18.152431,
  u'id': 35631,,
 {u'otherId': u'A1624903783',
  u'positionOrActive': 0,
  'searchScore': 18.152431,
  u'id': 35632,
 {u'otherId': u'A1624904100',
  u'positionOrActive': 0,
  'searchScore': 18.152431,
  u'id': 35633,]
```

settings

```
{
  "issuersearch": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "1s",
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "issuersearch",
        "creation_date": "1602687790617",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "edge_ngram_filter": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "2",
              "max_gram": "80"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
              "filter": Array[2][
                "lowercase",
                "edge_ngram_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
            },
            "short_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
              "filter": Array[2][
                "lowercase",
                "edge_ngram_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "case_sensitive": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "token_chars": Array[2][
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ],
              "min_gram": "2",
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "max_gram": "40"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "dexqFx32RXy-AC3HHpfElA",
        "version": {
          "created": "5060599"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening due to `standard` tokenizer which split the tokens on whitespace, you need to provide the complete example(full-index mapping, sample docs, and actual results for your search query to confirm it).

Also, hope you are not using any [search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) on your `name` field.

Comment: Ive also tried using an ngram tokenizer instead that uses the appropriate ngram sizes. The file still gets indexed correctly. There are no whitespaces in the text and a search analyzer isn't being used. Still leads to the same issues.

Comment: @Dex can you add your complete index mapping and your sample docs and search query.

Comment: Added! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dex thanks but search query which you provided is on the `otrherId` field, while you mentioned the `name` field which contains different data . Also you didn't provide your sample data.

Comment: Sorry! I had just said the name field at the start as an example. It's an issue I'm having across multiple fields. This is the exact info for one of the fields I'm using which is the in the format AXXXXXXX. The results are my docs. they are just formatted id is _id, score is search score and others are the relevant fields.

Comment: @Dex can you run the GET `_settings` API on your index and provide?

Comment: @Dex, I get your issue but as mentioned it should not be the case and I need the complete reproducible example

Comment: Ok! I added the settings from the api